# Trying to implement inline Webworker for a recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, web-worker

I have a first version of using a recursive function with Javascript which produces expected results. Below a working version :

```
// Call the recursive function and get final (a,b) results
var HitTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent));
var result= recursiveFunction(HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes);
var a = HitTemp.coordPlayable[0];
var b = HitTemp.coordPlayable[1];

// Recursive function
function recursiveFunction(HitCurrent, colorCurrent, depth) {
 // Indices
 var i, j, k;
 // Evaluation
 var arrayTemp, eval, e;
 // Set current color to HitCurrent
 HitCurrent.playerCurrent = colorCurrent;
 // Deep copy of arrayCurrent array
 arrayTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.arrayCurrent));
 // If depth equal to 0
 if (depth == 0)
  return evaluation(HitCurrent);
 // Starting evaluation
 eval = -infinity;
 // Browse all possible hits
 for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
   if (HitCurrent.arrayPlayable[i][j] == 'playable') {
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
     // Explore line started from (i,j) with direction "k"
     exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, i, j, k, 'drawing');
    }
    // Recursive call
    e = recursiveFunction(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent)), ((JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.playerCurrent) == JSON.stringify(playerBlack)) ? playerWhite : playerBlack), depth-1);
    if (e > eval) {
     HitCurrent.coordPlayable = [i,j];
     eval = e;
    }
   }
   // Restore arrayCurrent array
   HitCurrent.arrayCurrent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayTemp));
   }
 return eval;
}
```

From this, I would like to use "inline" WebWorkers to dedicate the recursion to WebWorker and avoid hanging process in browsers.

I tried to follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21831298/how-to-implement-a-recursive-function-as-a-web-worker?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) and [this other link](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/#toc-inlineworkers)

I don't know if I have to "`postmessage`" the object `HitCurrent` or the value `eval` to the main thread : by using WebWorker, I make confusions between the `return` instruction (which returns a value in the terminal case) and the objet `HitCurrent` argument passed for next recursive call.

If someone could give some clues to reproduce this original algorithm by using inline webworker (or with classical way of using webworker).

Comment: Are you using global variables in this case? If yes then you need to use them like `self.variablename` inside a web worker, in main code you can use it like `variablename` or `window.variablename`

Comment: Actually `self.variablename` is compatible in both window and worker. So you can try with that

Comment: Can you share your failing code and the error you are getting?

Comment: For the Worker, there is no difference if you loaded it from a real file on your server or from a blobURI, i.e don't get confused by this *inline-worker* name, that's just to make it look cool. To your question, you will have to pass to your worker script the `HitCurrent` object, how? It depends where it comes from. It might make sense to post it from the main thread through postMessage, in which case you'd have to grab it from the worker's `onmessage` event handler, or it might also make sense to fetch it from your server, but we can't tell since you didn't gave us anything.

Comment: As to what you'll do with the result, well you'll post it back to the main thread through worker's `self.postMessage`, and grab it from main thread through `worker.onmessage` event handler.

Comment: -@Kaiido, thanks I am going to make tests with your advices to handle `HitCurrent` object and `return` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline webworker example:

As your code, there is no `function evaluation`, `function exploreHitLine`.
Before use following code, you must insert them into `code`.

```
{
    let workerScript = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ `
    "use strict";
    // Recursive function
    function recursiveFunction( HitCurrent, colorCurrent, depth ) {
        // Indices
        var i, j, k;
        // Evaluation
        var arrayTemp, eval, e;
        // Set current color to HitCurrent
        HitCurrent.playerCurrent = colorCurrent;
        // Deep copy of arrayCurrent array
        arrayTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.arrayCurrent));
        // If depth equal to 0
        if ( depth === 0 ) return evaluation(HitCurrent);
        // Starting evaluation
        eval = -infinity;
        // Browse all possible hits
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (HitCurrent.arrayPlayable[i][j] === 'playable') {
                    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                        // Explore line started from (i,j) with direction "k"
                        exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, i, j, k, 'drawing');
                    }
                    // Recursive call
                    e = recursiveFunction(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent)), ((JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.playerCurrent) == JSON.stringify(playerBlack)) ? playerWhite : playerBlack), depth-1);
                    if (e > eval) {
                        HitCurrent.coordPlayable = [i,j];
                        eval = e;
                    }
                }
                // Restore arrayCurrent array
                HitCurrent.arrayCurrent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayTemp));
            }
        }
        return eval;
    }
    onmessage = function ( event ) {
        let params = event.data;
        postMessage( { result: recursiveFunction( ...params ) } );
    }
        ` ], { type: "plain/text" } ) );


    // Call the recursive function and get final (a,b) results
    new Promise( resolve => {
        let HitTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent));
        let firstWorker = new Worker( workerScript );
        firstWorker.onmessage = function ( event ) {
            resolve( event.data ); //{ result: XXX }
        }
        firstWorker.postMessage( HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes );
    } ).then( ( { result } ) => {
        let [ a, b ] = result.coordPlayable;
        console.log( result );
    } );
}
```

Additionally following is working inline WebWorker:

```js
{
    let workerScript = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ `
    "use strict";
    onmessage = function ( event ) {
        let sum = 0, count = event.data;
        for ( let i = 0; i < count**count; i++ ) {
            sum += i;
        }
        postMessage( { result: sum, count } );
    }
    ` ], { type: "plain/text" } ) );
    let firstWorker = new Worker( workerScript );
    let firstAlive = setTimeout( () => {
        firstWorker.terminate();
        console.log( "terminated" );
    }, 3000 );
    firstWorker.onmessage = function ( event ) {
        clearTimeout( firstAlive );
        console.log( event.data );
    }
    firstWorker.postMessage( 10 );

    let secondWorker = new Worker( workerScript );
    let secondAlive = setTimeout( () => {
        secondWorker.terminate();
        console.log( "terminated" );
    }, 3000 );
    secondWorker.onmessage = function ( event ) {
        clearTimeout( secondAlive );
        console.log( event.data );
    }
    secondWorker.postMessage( 5 );

}
```

**Update 1.**

```js
{
    // Inline webworker version
    let workerScript = URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [ `
    "use strict";
    // Recursive function
    function recursiveFunction( HitCurrent, colorCurrent, depth ) {
        // Indices
        var i, j, k;
        // Evaluation
        var arrayTemp, evaluated, e;
        // Set current color to HitCurrent
        HitCurrent.playerCurrent = colorCurrent;
        // Deep copy of arrayCurrent array
        arrayTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.arrayCurrent));
        // If depth equal to 0
        if (depth == 0)
        return evaluation(HitCurrent);
        // Starting evaluation
        evaluated = -infinity;
        // Browse all possible hits
        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (HitCurrent.arrayPlayable[i][j] == 'playable') {
                    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
                        // Explore line started from (i,j) with direction "k"
                        exploreHitLine(HitCurrent, i, j, k, 'drawing');
                    }
                    // Recursive call
                    e = recursiveFunction(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent)), ((JSON.stringify(HitCurrent.playerCurrent) == JSON.stringify(playerBlack)) ? playerWhite : playerBlack), depth-1);
                    if ( e > evaluated ) {
                        HitCurrent.coordPlayable = [i,j];
                        evaluated = e;
                    }
                    if (e == -infinity) { HitCurrent.coordPlayable = [ i, j ]; }
                    // Restore arrayCurrent array
                    HitCurrent.arrayCurrent = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(arrayTemp));
                }
            }
        }
        return evaluated;
    }

    onmessage = function ( event ) {
        let params = event.data;
        //postMessage( { result: recursiveFunction(  HitCurrent, HitCurrent.playerCurrent, maxNodes ) } );
        postMessage( { result: recursiveFunction( ...params ) } );
    };
    ` ], { type: "plain/text" } ) );


   // Call the recursive function and get final (a,b) results
    new Promise( resolve => {
        let HitTemp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(HitCurrent));
        let firstWorker = new Worker( workerScript );
        firstWorker.onmessage = function ( event ) {
            resolve( event.data ); //{ result: XXX }
        }
        firstWorker.postMessage( [ HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes ] );
    } ).then( ( { result } ) => {
        let [ a, b ] = result.coordPlayable;
        console.log( result );
    } );
}
```

Explanation of my faults:

1. It is impossible to use "eval" as the name of a variable when in "strict mode".

=>

from: `eval`

to: `evaluated`

2. `Worker.postMessage( aMessage, Transferrable )`, in this case, you don't need to use the second parameter.

=>

from: `firstWorker.postMessage( HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes );`

to: `firstWorker.postMessage( [ HitTemp, HitTemp.playerCurrent, maxNodes ] );`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/postMessage)

3. Continue to 2, passing parameter to recursiveFunction is fixed.

Comment: -@Isitea : thanks for your code snippet, however, I get 2 unexpected errors at execution, could you tale a look please at my **UPDATE 1** , especially at the line `postMessage( { result: recursiveFunction( ...params ) } );`?

Comment: -@Isitea : excuse me but if I run your last code snippet or include in my code, I get the following error : `Error : {
  "message": "SyntaxError: missing : after property id",`: any idea ?

Comment: This answer is plenty to understand and resolve the question. @youpilat13 I'm not seeing that error in the runnable snippets, so check yourself for syntax errors or runtime issues. If you're on an IE11 or something, it may not support implied prop names, so `{ HitTemp }` needs to be `{ HitTemp: HitTemp }`

Comment: -@Isitea Thanks for the last fix, I was trying with "`{`" instead of "`[`" and that was not working. Now, I think that syntax is correct : a last thing, I get a "**ReferenceError: HitCurrent is not defined**" error, surely a problem of scope at the line `postMessage( { result: recursiveFunction( HitCurrent, HitCurrent.playerCurrent, maxNodes ) } );` between `onmessage` function and main thread. Anyway, you deserve the award for all your help, I keep on debugging this last error. regards

Comment: @Isitea Hello ! could you take a look please at my **UPDATE 2**, I would like to know what your little code does, Regards

Comment: @youpilat13 The first console log is the result of the second worker, and the second console log, terminated, is messages for force termination of the first worker.

Comment: @Isitea . thanks but do you stop the first webworker once the second is finished ?, you mean that second worker wil finish before 3 seconds unlikely the first worker ? so when one reaches 3 seconds, the first worker is forced to be terminated, even if the computing of sum is not finished, isn't it ? regards

Comment: @youpilat13 Yes, that's right. The first worker calculates the sum of 1 to 10000000000 and the second worker calculates the the sum of 1 to 3125.

Answer (score 0):

- `eval` is a keyword; use some other variable name.
- `postMessage` only
  accepts one argument (it also accepts a transferable, but that is not applicable to your case), and if that argument is not a primitive value, it should
  be an object that can be serializable (e.g. you cannot pass functions
  or methods directly to the web worker)

I might be misunderstanding what you are trying to do, but you might want to reconsider recursively spawning an *unkown* number of webworkers! Just spawn *one* webworker and pass the parameters of your function to it and do your recursive calculations inside that webworker synchronously without spawning a new worker, if you just want to free up your main stack. Spawning too many web workers will consume a lot of a resources and will actually slow down your calculations! FYI, spawning each new web worker takes ~40ms and takes up resources. This is a general observation with regard to utilizing multithreading for calculating recursive functions! This might help:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/238729/can-recursion-be-done-in-parallel-would-that-make-sense

---

> Concerning all functions called into URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( ... )) block, Have I got to include them in this block or can I write them outside of it (as you say for evaluation and explotHitLine functions) ?

Your webworker is a completely separate JS file and execution context; you will not have access to anything that is not defined within its context or send to it as a message.

---

Btw, there are a few errors in your code which will prevent it from compiling correctly anyways: `infinity` should be `Infinity`, `playerBlack` and `playerWhite` are undefined, etc.